# How can convert file with contents of string to the file with contents of byte?

Tags: java, string, file, arrays

I wrote the following code to convert file of string to the file of byte data.But the input file and the output file are the same. What is the problem of my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class StringToBytes {


 private static void convertor(Stream<String> input) throws IOException
 {

     File file = new File("byteTest.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

    Iterator<String> it= input.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        byte []b= it.next().getBytes();
        writer.write(b);

    }
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Path path= Paths.get("test.txt");

    Stream<String>lines=Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    convertor(lines);
}
}
```

The content of my input file is:

```
San Francisco, officially the City and County of San Francisco, is the cultural center and a leading financial hub of the San Francisco Bay Area and Northern California. 
The only consolidated city-county in California
```

I want the output(byteTest.txt) file has somthing like

```
[B@2dda6444
```

instead the content of the output file is the same as input file.

Comment: What do you mean by "context of the file" - do you mean the *contents* of the file? If so, files are *always* sequences of bytes... it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. Additionally, calling `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @ JonSkeet I edit my explaination.I mean content.

Comment: Do you want the ascii binary string representation? I.e. c = "1100001", g = "1100111" and print that to a file?

Comment: *Why* would you want the file to contain `[B@2dda6444`? That's the output of calling `toString()` on a byte array, but it doesn't really contain any useful information... it's still unclear what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: B@2dda6444 is the byte's memory location in the jvm, why would you want that?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I have compress function which gives `byte[]` and then compress the data and I want compress the contents of the file.Therefore, I think, I should convert the contents of the file to byte then call the compress function to read from it.

Comment: [B@2dda6444 only reflects the String's (or byte array's) location NOT it's content.

Comment: Then show an example of the compress function, it's much more likely that it works something like this
`Byte[] compressText(inputStringFromFile.getBytes());`
Then you should write the byte array you get back to a file.

Comment: You need to read what `toString` actually returns. Since this method is inherited from Object (arrays are Objects) take a look at  [this JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) to see that it returns `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. BTW hashing is one way compression, it will not let you get original data because same hash can be get from different bytes (for instance Strings `"Aa"` and `"BB"` have the same hash 2112 so we can't make sure which value was used to generate this hash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially copying the contents of a file...You're getting what you would normally get if you copy/pasted the file (Each ASCII character is a byte)

If your aim is to compact the file, right now your file is a tightly packed as it can be, without an actual compression algorithm being run on it.

Comment: I want the whole contents of the file is converted to `byte[]` instead of string.I mean I want the file with contents of byte not String.

Comment: A file is simply a sequence of bytes. A file has no type, like object types in C#, Java, etc. Open up a binary file on your machine in notepad (.dll will work). Notepad will show a string of nonsense characters - Because its trying to interpret the bytes as characters. But really its binary data, not string data.

Comment: @user3487667: Again, I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding what a file contains. It's just a sequence of bytes. It's only a string if you *interpret* it that way.

Comment: @ Mentok and @ Jon Skeet Thank you I undesrtand now.